# Put something to $_SESSION from database

Tags: php, session

i am trying to add few things to session when user log in. For example user_level, or id.

So my code looks like this:

```
 public function userLogin() {
     $success = false;
     try{
        $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS ); 
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1";

        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();

        $valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $this->username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $stmt->fetchColumn(1);

        if( $valid ) {
            $success = true;
        }
        $con = null;
        return $success;
     }catch (PDOException $e) {
         echo $e->getMessage();
         return $success;
     }
```

So as u can see i am adding ***username*** and trying to add ***id*** as well. Username works fine but as soon as i take id from database i have some problem there. Its not stored, actualy if i var_dump it it says `bool(false)`

Can somebody tell me what i am doing wrong? Or gimme some advise. I also wonder if this is secure to store things like user level and id in session to limit access for some part of website.

Comment: `$stmt->fetchColumn(1);` is probably not doing what you expect it to do

Comment: yea probably, i try to follow this article (http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php ) but yea i may be wrong

Comment: try $stmt->debugDumpParams() what it shows?

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $stmt->fetchColumn(1);
```

considering your id column is named id, use

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
$_SESSION['id'] = $rows[0]['id'];
```

Directly from PHP docs :

> fetchColumn returns a single column from the next row of a result set or FALSE if there are no more rows.

Comment: If you really want to use $stmt->fetchColumn() make sure you know which column is your id and then use it for your "valid" check. Then make $_SESSION['id'] = $valid. Your problem is that you are calling fetchColumn() twice and the first one pulls in the first row and the second call tries to grab a second row that doesnt exist so it returns false. However using FETCH_ASSOC allows you to make sure to ALWAYS grab the id no matter what column its in. I would suggest using that. If your really

Comment: @ProgrammerJeff Hey mate, thanks for your answer, it have some logic and i understand now what i did wrong, unfortunately it didnt fix the problem. It stil display nothing in $_SESSION['id']  
Also i was thinking if `$rows[0]['id'];`  id in this code mean name of colum, if yea my colum name is usedID (i changed it and try also with no effect)

Comment: @MartinFerko Yes, you have to replace 'id' with your column name ('usedID'). 

Are you sure your query actually return a row ? And also why use LIMIT 1 ? Only one row should when searching by username unless your DB is strangely designed.